# Getting something went wrong everytime when trying to verify phone auth- Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication, ios11

I have integrated firebase phone auth in my app and it was working perfect earlier, from few days i am getting alert something went wrong when trying to verify.

So i thought to update sdk with updated one- 
When i am updating firebase sdk and its crashing here all time-

```
 FIRPhoneAuthProvider *provider = [FIRPhoneAuthProvider providerWithAuth:self.auth];
      [provider verifyPhoneNumber:phoneNumberWithCountryCode
                       UIDelegate:self
                       completion:^(NSString *_Nullable verificationID, NSError *_Nullable error)
```

Crash log- 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

What is the issue anyone can suggest?